# Spring: @BootstrapWith for ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Currently I use @BootstrapWith annotation in conjunction with custom class, which is simply sets some system properties used in test. However (as far as I understand it) those properties are being set each time TestContextManager instantiates test and TestContext with it:

> @BootstrapWith is a class-level annotation that is used to configure
>   how the Spring TestContext Framework is bootstrapped

[spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html)

Is there any way to set properties once before ApplicationContext is started?

**Edit:**

I cannot use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` due to parameterized tests, which require `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`. I use `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule` instead

Additionally I run not only parameterized tests, but ordinary tests as well. Thus I cannot simply extend `Parameterized` runner

Comment: do you mean `System.getProperties()`?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski System.setProperty() before ApplicationContext is launched

Comment: Do you have to set properties globally or should they be different for each test suite?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski they should be globally available or at least in current ApplicationContext. I cannot bind them to the suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the most basic way of setting some properties before `ApplicationContext` sets up is to write custom runner, like that:

```
public class MyRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public MyRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
        System.setProperty("sample.property", "hello world!");
    }

}
```

And then you can use it instead your current runner.

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
//....
```

If your current runner seems to be declared final, you can possibly use aggregation (but I have not tested in) instead of inheritance.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/1c3a80564158da54fb9346e1a80fbf7d) you can find a sample Gist where this runner is used and property gets successfully resolved.

*update*

If you don't want to use custom Runner (although you could have several runners setting properties for each case - with parameters, without parameters, and so on). You can use `@ClassRule` which works on static fields/methods - take a look at the example below:

```
@ClassRule
public static ExternalResource setProperties() {
    return new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
            System.setProperty("sample.property", "hello world!");
            return super.apply(base, description);
        }
    };
}
```

This **static** method is to be placed in your test class.

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned it in question: I cannot use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) due to parameterized tests, which require @RunWIth(Parameterized.class). I use SpringClassRule and SpringMethodRule instead

Comment: @Anton Why not extend `Parameterized` runner?

Comment: in that case I will not be able to set properties for ordinary, not parameterized tests

Comment: Thank you. I posted additional answer below, but will accept your answer in gratitude for spent time

Answer (score 1):

If it's just `Properties` that you want to add as part of the bootstrapping of the spring application context you can use the annotation `@TestPropertySource` at the top of your Junit test class like this...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={SpringConfig.class,SpringConfigForTests.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = "runDate=20180110")
public class AcceptanceTests {
...
```

I use this technique to load my production `SpringConfig` class (which loads properties files), then override some beans specifically for testing in `SpringConfigForTests` (and potentially loading test specific properties files), then adding the another run-time property named `runDate`.

I am using Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE and it looks like this annotation has been included since 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this is possible with extending `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` (or any other `ContextLoader`) and overriding `prepareContext()` method:

```
@Override
protected void prepareContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
    // set properties here
    super.prepareContext(context, mergedConfig);
}
```

Than custom loader should be specified in `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on test instance

Answer (score 0):

If you are ultimately consuming the program arguments as an `ApplicationArguments` then you can simply provide an `ApplicationArguments` in the test context. It will be in conflict with the empty-argument one provided via `@SpringBootTest` but you can force yours to be used by annotating it `@Primary`.

```
@Component
public class ArgReadingBean {
  public ArgReadingBean(ApplicationArguments arguments) {
    // ...
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class, ArgDependentBean.class })
public class AppArgsTest {
  @Resource
  private ArgReadingBean bean;

  public static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    ApplicationArguments myArguments() {
      return new DefaultApplicationArguments("-help");
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testArgs() {
    assertThat(bean).isNotNull(); // or whatever
  }
}
```